# FuentD Rollover alias for AWS OpenSearch ILM

Tags: alias, fluentd, rollover, opensearch, ilm

I have logging infrastructure setup with AWS OpenSearch, Fluent-bit (DaemonSet on EKS), FluentD (Deployment on EKS) and OpenSearch Dashboard.

I am working on the ILM policy and facing issue with the rollover. I am trying to achieve with the policy, after reaching the condition (after every 1 days or when the index reaches size 2G), the rollover should happen  and moved to cold storage. Once the old index reaches 7 days in total, the old index should get deleted.

My FluentD config:

```
<match *.**>   
  @type copy
  <store>
    type elasticsearch  
    include_tag_key true
    host "#{ENV.fetch('ELASTICSEARCH_HOST')}"
    port "#{ENV.fetch('ELASTICSEARCH_PORT')}"
    user "#{ENV.fetch('ELASTICSEARCH_USER')}"
    password "#{ENV.fetch('ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD')}"
    log_es_400_reason true
    ca_file /certs/ca.pem
    scheme https
    ssl_verify true 
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix rollover-sbx
 </match>
```

ILM policy

{
"id": "sbx-ism-policy",
"seqNo": 379851,
"primaryTerm": 2,
"policy": {
"policy_id": "sbx-ism-policy",
"description": "A simple default policy that changes the replica count between hot and cold states.",
"last_updated_time": 1650595677042,
"schema_version": 12,
"error_notification": null,
"default_state": "hot",
"states": [
{
"name": "hot",
"actions": [
{
"rollover": {
"min_size": "200mb",
"min_doc_count": 200,
"min_index_age": "1h"
}
}
],
"transitions": [
{
"state_name": "cold",
"conditions": {
"min_index_age": "1h"
}
}
]
},
{
"name": "cold",
"actions": [
{
"close": {}
}
],
"transitions": []
}
],
"ism_template": [
{
"index_patterns": [
"rollover-sbx*"
],
"priority": 70,
"last_updated_time": 1650583513796
}
]
}
}

above mentioned min size and time in ILM policy are for testing purpose

Comment: Current FluentD config:`log_es_400_reason true
ca_file /certs/ca.pem
scheme https
ssl_verify true
 logstash_format true
logstash_prefix rollover-sbx
ilm_policy_id sbx-ism-policy
template_name sbx-rollover
logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
reload_connections false
reconnect_on_error true
reload_on_failure true
request_timeout 15s
flush_interval 10s`

Comment: Getting below error while the index trying to rollover
    "message": "Missing rollover_alias index setting [index=rollover-sbx-20220422]"